Failed to solve constraints: (k ≤ 5) x (k * 2 ≡ 5). How could I make this work?
I'm new to agda and trying to prove that 5 is prime :).
I'm now trying to dismiss that 2 is a divisor of 5. I have:
p1 : k * 2 ≡ 5
p2 : k ≤ 5

I would now hope that pattern matching like:
case (p2 ,′ p1 ) of λ where ()

would typecheck as there's 6 terms fulfilling p2 and none of them fulfills p1. Doesn't seem like the computational budget should get exceeded so quickly, no?
Is there a way to make it work? How else can i continue with p1 and p2 and in general: how to prove 5 is prime or that 2 does not divide it?

case ( p2 ) of λ where         p2' -> case ( p1 ) of λ where ()
doesnt work either

Agda does not attempt to do proof-search, you have to either manually guide it like in @NaïmFavier's answer or use a solver such as Schmitty.

Let's try defining the following:
goal : ∀ k → (k ≤ 5) × (k * 2 ≡ 5) → ⊥

If we simply bind all the variables, we have
Goal: ⊥
y : k * 2 ≡ 5
x : k ≤ 5
k : ℕ

While we can see that this is absurd, Agda cannot: each of the premises is possible in isolation, and Agda is not going to try checking every possible value of k because it wouldn't know when to stop. So we have to guide it by making the appropriate case split ourselves. Let's see what happens if  we split on k once:
goal (suc k) (x , y) = {!   !}

Now Agda was able to discard the zero case as absurd, because in that case we have y : zero ≡ suc (suc (suc (suc (suc zero)))), which is impossible. We are left with the suc k case, which is still not immediately absurd. Let's split on k two more times:
goal (suc (suc zero)) (x , y) = {!   !}
goal (suc (suc (suc k))) (x , y) = {!   !}

Now Agda can see that both of these cases are absurd, because in the first one we have y : 4 ≡ 5 and in the second one we have y : 6 + k * 2 ≡ 5, which reduces to suc (k * 2) ≡ zero. We can't just discard both cases though, because Agda needs to know it should make those splits. Thus the simplest definition that works is
goal : ∀ k → (k ≤ 5) × (k * 2 ≡ 5) → ⊥
goal 2 ()

Agda will create a case tree that includes 2 and see that each case is absurd (this would work with a higher number as well). Note that we have not used the k ≤ 5 argument.

A more principled approach would be to use proof by reflection: for example, if you can prove that divisibility of natural numbers is decidable, then the proof doubles as an effective decision procedure for divisibility. You can then ask Agda whether 2 divides 5 and extract a proof from the (negative) answer.

Hey, thanks, but I don't get it at all.
What works as well is if I pattern match on just s<=s (s<=s z<=n). How does this work if it's not the only way a number can be smaller that 5? How can this work if I list just one pattern and why it works with any pattern of the bunch?

Agda can only know that the second pattern is absurd when k is either 0, 1, 2 or of the form suc (suc (suc m)), so you have to guide it to make that split somehow. Honestly I don't have a very good mental model of absurd patterns and found that more or less by trial and error. A more principled approach would be using proof by reflection, see this gist for example.

but is this only because of the depth of the search? Because 1) when k is 4 it is not the case that 4 * 2 is 5 in the same way it is not the case for 0, 1 and 2, right? And 2) in that pattern by default k = 4 or 5 is admissible as well. If agda can dismiss this case, why does it struggle with 0, 1, 2?
Because I've also tried with other number of s<=s constructors, my guess is that by doing that hack we make it easier for agda to search the space - BUT if so a) i dont understand why b) I would want to parametrize the compiler with bigger budget for search.
thanks

There is no budget to make bigger, Agda doesn't do proof search by default. I've edited my answer with more details.

thanks a lot. So what I got is that agda verifies a single pattern is empty if that's the case. But if in isolation the pattern is not empty, but a conjunction of few patterns is - then agda doesn't do any search to find that out.
Btw, when you wrote "simplest case that works", you meant that repeated for not only k=2, but also k=3, k=1 and so on, right?
thanks

No, just one number (≥ 2) is enough to tell Agda how deep it should split, and then every other branch in the case tree is absurd.
